# How do i completely remove django-registration?

Tags: django, settings, uninstallation, django-registration

I have installed and old version by mistake of django-registration and it seems quite complicated to fix it to the new one. So since i am just starting a project anew, how can I uninstall completely the module django-registration?

Comment: How did you install it? Using setup.py? Using pip? Did you just put it on your pythonpath somewhere? What platform are you using?

Comment: I think i installed it with easy_install django-registration on linux and also i put it on my mac too. Since I am a newbie, I can't figure out where it went. I would have loved it to be in my project folder and just copy to my next project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the folder `/usr/local/pythonX.Y/site-packages/django-registration` where `X.Y` is your python version, which you can find by running `python --version`

Comment: I am looking at my computer locally first. the path is different:
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/
and also, there is not djang-registration folder there, just django_registration-0.7-py2.6.egg

on the linux server:
/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ 
and i have no django-registration there whatsoever. 

utterly confused

Comment: Remove the egg then. :)
site-packages, not dist-packages.

Comment: is there a difference? mac has only site-packages. linux server only dist-packages

Comment: it turns out the django_registration-0.7-py2.6.egg is a folder. i removed it. Is there anything else to do? Like remove paths somewhere?

Comment: No that's it. On your linux server, do 'sudo updatedb; locate django_registration' or 'locate django-registration' and remove anything you find.

Comment: sounds good, but with su user i get: bash: updatedb: command not found. googling it, seems like it has to come default on linux systems like ubuntu lucid (slicehost). am i using it wrong ? tried both user with su and logging as root and simply updatedb

Answer (score 1):

If pip is installed then simply fire following command, that's it.

`pip uninstall django-registration`

Also you can confirm it by going to `/lib` directory at root or at virtual environment level.

e.g.

`/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`

If you cant see directory named `registration` means django-registration has been removed.